# AWS SWF in Spring boot

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-swf

Can someone point me to Amazon SWF implementation in **Spring boot**. I am not able to find much examples. I am getting a **nullpointer** exception as I am trying to access workflow with auto generated external client. Any working example in spring boot to use *internal client* to access SWF.

Comment: I don't understand how Spring Boot is related to AWS SWF. Isn't this just a standard Java thing, like described here? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/swf-hello.html

Comment: SWF requires the use of custom scopes. So integration with Spring is not super straightforward. And I believe the actual Spring Boot support was never added.

Comment: Thanks @Maxim Fateev. Can you please suggest me a workaround to get this work. My workflow execution is getting started but fails with **WorkflowExecutionFailed** event and the error is null pointer exception

Comment: You need to provide more information. For example stack trace of NPE.